# Uppload file to remote server using asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, upload, system.io.file

Can any body tell me how can i specify a path on a remote server to save the file on ot using fileuppload.saveas() in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

You can simply save your file or move or file in any folder you want

```
string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/foldername/") + filename + fileextension);
```

Comment: I know for that but my uppload page is on web server and i want the user to uppload files on another server

Comment: then i think you must use something like this FileUpload1.Copy(filepath, "\\\\192.168.1.28\\Files\\"); instead of  FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/foldername/") + filename + fileextension);